# Does Struts 2.5.5 support Java 1.6

Tags: java, struts2, version

Does Struts 2.5.5 (latest version) support Java 1.6.x, as i'm seeing unsupported version when running a sample application.

Comment: What exactly is the error message you are seeing?

Comment: Unsupported version 51

Comment: The could really document this somewhere...   Looking at the `pom.xml` in the source repository it is built for JDK7 with an optional build for JDK8. So I guess: "no, JDK6 is not supported".

Comment: Can you point me the folder which you are looking at

Comment: Nevermind, i found it here
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Version+Notes+2.5

Comment: *The 2.5.x series of the Apache Struts framework has a minimum requirement of the following specification versions: Servlet API 2.4, JSP API 2.0, and Java 7.* - https://struts.apache.org/announce.html.

Comment: @Thilo OP doesn't ask you to use JDK6, Java 1.6 can be compiled on JDK7,8 as well.

Comment: @MVVRMurthy Can you recompile your Java 1.6 code with JDK 7?

Answer (score -1):

Indeed struts2.5.5 is using `maven-compiler-plugin` which has in [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/f2348e53cbdf8ad7d9c28c66dc6fefe2c5718636/pom.xml)

```xml
<configuration>
   <source>1.7</source>
   <target>1.7</target>
</configuration>
```

It means that it supports 1.6 due backword compatibility of java versions, but it's binary incompatible and needs to recompile the code with above configuration.

Comment: What do you mean by "it supports 1.6". It clearly does not, and you cannot just recompile targeting 1.6 (as it is bound to use newer platform features).

Comment: @Thilo *It means that it supports 1.6 due backword compatibility of java versions, but it's binary incompatible and needs to recompile the code with above configuration.*

Comment: @Thilo Did you ever compile any source of Struts2 application?

Comment: @Thilo *you cannot just recompile targeting 1.6* - Where did you see that used targeting 1.6?

Comment: @Thilo Can you explain what, how and where *it is bound to use newer platform features*, also what features do you mean?